# MS SQL Server cannot call methods on ntext

Tags: sql-server, view, ntext

I am trying to create a view in MS SQL server from a table. The table name is Account_Plan and I am trying to create a view as Account_Plan_vw. While executing the DDL to create the view, I am getting the error as shown below.

> Msg 258, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Account_Plan_vw, Line 56
>   Cannot call methods on ntext
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Account_Plan_vw, Line 22
>   Invalid column name 'How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objective2__c'.

The error message shows the column 'How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objective2__c' as invalid. However, this is a valid column in the Account_Plan table of ntext type.

Can someone help? I just removed the extra columns from the Create view statement.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Account_Plan_vw]
AS
SELECT   
 Results_1.Account__c
,Results_1.How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objectives__c
,Results_1.How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objective2__c
FROM 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY apc1.Account__c ORDER BY apc1.Year__c DESC, apc1.CreatedDate DESC) AS RN_1
    ,apc1.Account__c
,apc1.How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objectives__c
,apc1.How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objective2__c
  FROM Account_Plan apc1
  INNER JOIN RecordType rtp1
  ON apc1.RecordTypeId=rtp1.[Id]
  AND rtp1.DeveloperName = 'Account_Plan' 
  INNER JOIN Account acc1
  ON acc1.[Id] = apc1.Account__c
  WHERE apc1.Year__c <= YEAR(GETDATE())
  ) AS Results_1
  WHERE RN_1 = 1
```

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Comment: I am not able to add the code here. I am getting an error message saying comment is long.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47168524/edit) your question and add your code there.

Comment: I did that now.

Comment: What happens if you create your view using the code posted (i.e. without the extra columns)?

Comment: Did not try that. Will try that tomorrow morning and see what happens.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

NTEXT is deprecated, convert it to NVARCHAR(MAX) instead

see: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql)

**You should consider altering the table** not just casting in the view, but:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Account_Plan_vw]
AS
SELECT
      results_1.Account__c
    , results_1.How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objectives__c
    , results_1.How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objective2__c
FROM (
      SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY apc1.Account__c ORDER BY apc1.Year__c DESC, apc1.CreatedDate DESC) AS rn_1
          , apc1.Account__c
          , apc1.How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objectives__c
          , cast(apc1.How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objective2__c as nvarchar(max)) as How_the_CU_will_achieve_these_objective2__c
      FROM Account_Plan apc1
      INNER JOIN RecordType rtp1 ON apc1.RecordTypeId = rtp1.[Id]
            AND rtp1.DeveloperName = 'Account_Plan'
      INNER JOIN Account acc1 ON acc1.[Id] = apc1.Account__c
      WHERE apc1.Year__c <= YEAR(GETDATE())
) AS results_1
WHERE RN_1 = 1
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the initial question. If you search the internet for this question, you will find examples of a similar question about `VARCHAR`. The problem being seems to be an obscure syntax error.

Comment: @Alex but you will also find that the solutions to such questions are to  cast/convert to supported data types (n)varchar instead of (n)text - do refer to the MS warning about the deprecated types. **Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.**

Comment: `NTEXT` is still a supported data type, hence should not be a problem on its own. I would also like to see examples you are referencing where casting `NTEXT` to `VARCHAR( MAX )` solved the problem. I have not found any, except some dealing with `NTEXT` to `XML` conversion.

Comment: @Alex regret that I am not doing further research on this. I don't understand why you consider them to be supported data types. Take it up with Microsoft  Support perhaps? The reference I provided is from Microsoft.

Comment: They are currently supported because deprecated means supported for now but its use is discouraged. My initial comment was about your answer having nothing to do with the OP's error.

Comment: @Alex thank you for the semantic advice. If you can locate any solution to that error message that does not involve **casting to the recommend equivalent data type** please do provide that information, or perhaps add your own answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. Unfortunately I do not have the liberty of altering the table Account_Plan as it is getting replicated from Salesforce CRM using the SF_Replicate command using DBAMP connector. The Long Text Area fields in Salesforce object Account_Plan__c is automatically mapped to NTEXT fields. I will try the cast solution while creating the view and see whether it helps or not. FYI, the long text area in Salesforce can handle upto 32,768 characters, but I guess ntext can handle only upto 8000 characters. So, there might be some truncation issue.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I figured the issue and it was somewhat cryptic to find. The salesforce object had a field as last_peer_review_date__c for which no permissions were given to anybody. As a result, DBAMP user was not able to see the field and hence missed to create this field in SQL server when I used the SF_Replicate command. The create view SQL was created by me couple of weeks ago and it did work at that time. Now, when I used the same SQL, it failed because the SQL had the last_peer_review_date field, but the Account_Plan table does not.

Comment: To fix the issue, I had to do the following.  1) Change permissions on the field last_peer_review_date in Salesforce 2) Drop the table Account_Plan in SQL server 3) Replicate the Account_Plan table using SF_Replicate and 4) Execute the create view statement again. It worked fine now.

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it. Then there is a clear record of the csuse. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the issue and it was somewhat cryptic to find. The salesforce object had a field as last_peer_review_date__c for which no permissions were given to anybody. As a result, DBAMP user was not able to see the field and hence missed to create this field in SQL server when I used the SF_Replicate command. The create view SQL was created by me couple of weeks ago and it did work at that time. Now, when I used the same SQL, it failed because the SQL had the last_peer_review_date field, but the Account_Plan table does not.

Balaji Pooruli